# Where do you download the current firmware for the Galaxy Note II?

Tags: device-firmware, samsung-galaxy-note-2

I bricked my phone via the official Kies update function and now I want to restore it with Odin. However, I find no place where you can download the current firmware files, most of the sites are only for registered users or the file is taken down... Does anyone know an official firmware repository or something similar? My model number is *GT-N7100*.

Comment: You may wish to include the model number of your Note II. Also, take a look [over here](http://galaxynote2root.com/galaxy-note-2-stock-firmwares/) and see if your model number is included. (Make sure you match the model number, not just the carrier).

Comment: @dotVezz My model number was included there, however I can't download because of an 'nginx error'...

Comment: See [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152) I think the Samdroid link there is probably the best bet for you.

Comment: @GAThrawn I don't think so, I have not found any valid stock ROM on these ones.

Comment: I'm seeing several firmwares for the N7100 on sammobile (linked from the mentioned reference question).  Just go [here](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/1/), select "smartphone", "Android", "GT-N7100", and your country and carrier.  Downloading the firmware requires registration, but that's free.

Comment: After a long search all over the net, I've finally found one at one of the sites mentioned at http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152.